# Replace many ranges in a string

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

I need to replace a string into T9 letters. Ex: "hello" will become "32445"

So far I have the following code, but each `Regex` takes up time, Is there any way to replace many ranges in simpler code?

```
dim tword = word    
tWord = Regex.Replace(tWord, "[abc]","1")
tWord = Regex.Replace(tWord, "[def]","2")
tWord = Regex.Replace(tWord, "[ghi]","3")
tWord = Regex.Replace(tWord, "[jkl]","4")
tWord = Regex.Replace(tWord, "[mno]","5")
tWord = Regex.Replace(tWord, "[pqrs]","6")
tWord = Regex.Replace(tWord, "[tuv]","7")
tWord = Regex.Replace(tWord, "[wxyz]", "8")
RTextBox.Text = RTextBox.Text.Replace(word, tWord)
```

Comment: `"[pqrs]"` would be written as `"[p-s]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(word, "[a-z]",
    Function(m) "11122233344455566667778888"(Asc(m.Value) - Asc("a"c)))
```

using a [Regex.Replace overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) whose third parameter is [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) that allows you an arbitrary replacement function.
Each [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) object including a matched string (containing only one alphabetic letter that matched in this case) is passed to the `MatchEvaluator`.

Inside the `MatchEvaluator` function,

- `m` is a `Match` object and `m.Value` indicates the matched string.
- `Asc(m.Value) - Asc("a"c)` converts an alphabet to an index 0-25.
- `"11122233344455566667778888"(index)` is invoking
  [`String.Chars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx)
  which is the default property of the `String` class, that is, converting an index to a digit.

Answer (score 1):

You could put all your letters in a map and do a quick lookup as you loop through all characters in the input string. This way you only have to process the input string once (your regex approach processes the string once for each regex).

```
'This is a one-time setup for the map
Dim map As New Dictionary(Of Char, Char)

map.Add("a"c, "1"c)
map.Add("b"c, "1"c)
map.Add("c"c, "1"c)
map.Add("d"c, "2"c)
'TODO add all other characters that you want to map

'...

Dim buffer As New StringBuilder(word.Length)
Dim chr As Char

For i As Integer = 0 To word.Length - 1
    'If the character appears in the map, use its mapped value
    If map.TryGetValue(word(i), chr) Then
        buffer.Append(chr)
    Else
        'If a character is not found, simply output the input
        'character (modify this behavior as needed)
        buffer.Append(word(i))
    End If
Next i

Dim result = buffer.ToString()
```